# transformation in the plane

Tags: geometry

a transformation in the plane transforms a point $P(x,y)$ in $P'\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right)$. I'd like to know how a line and a circumference which passes from the origin are trasformed and if the transformation preserves angles ... thanks

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: I noticed that x'/x = y'/y  but I don't know how to continue...

Comment: Let $O(0,0)$ be an origin. Note that for any point $P\neq O$ points $O$, $P$, $P'$ are collinear and equality $OP\cdot OP'=1$ holds. Hence, this transformation is just an inversion with respect to $O$ and radius 1.

Comment: It is not clear as to what you mean by `a line and a circumference'. In fact  if P is $z$ then P' is $1/\bar{z}$.. By the way, in Argand plane, if $z$ moves on a line, $w=1/\bar{z}$ would move on a circle..

Comment: So, have you tried simply applying the transformation to the generic equation of a line and working through the algebra?